# How to use tags$script in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

This is really something simple but I can't figure out what's happening.

Say I have this directory structure:

```
- app.R
- www
    |- script.js
```

`script.js`:

```js
alert("Hello World!");
```

When I use `includeScript()` in `app.R` it works fine and the alert is shown:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  includeScript(path = "www/script.js"),
  tags$h1("Hello World")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But when I use `tags$script` it doesn't work:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "script.js")
  ),
  tags$h1("Hello World")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I instead get a 404 error in the browser console in regards to `script.js`:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

How do I use `tags$script`? What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. For me, the alert is shown as expected in both cases. Are you invoking the app via `runApp("path/to/app.R")`?

Comment: Also consider taking a look at `shinyjs`. Youcan run `shinyjs::runjs` to execute JS from the server of your app. If `shinyjs` seems like it might address your question, I'd be happy to create an answer demonstrating how to use it.

Comment: @GregordeCillia Oh No! You mean that was the issue? I've spent like 2 days wondering whether they updated shiny docs and I missed something. This is my 4th year as an R shiny developer and I'm utterly ashamed. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JacobBumgarner Thanks for the suggestion, and I know it works but my question was why `tags$script` isn't working.

Comment: Works both ways.  Cannot reproduce your issue.